LTspice AC/DC converter with DC/DC boost converter
So this is my first time using LTspice and I need to convert my (AC) Vin 11.5V to DC and then boost DC voltage to Vout 22.5V. I have a few givens and some I needed to calculate. I am struggling to find Ripple Voltage and Ripple Current. I also dont know what values to allocate to my capacitor or inductor. (Continuous Conduction Mode)
Duty cycle is 0.5
I have a switching frequency of 270kHz,
AC frequency is 50Hz
average current load is 2.2A
Any notes or ideas would be amazing.


I'm rather weirded out by the direct application of a switch to L1 against a backdrop of a 50 Hz bridge rectifier without any attempt to develop a relatively stable DC source at the left end of L1. I've never seen it successfully attempted this way before and I'd love to see the analysis for it. (I would not love to do the analysis for it.) Would make for a very interesting white paper, I suspect. I guess this says I can't help with the question. :)

How would you recommend i attempt to stabilise the DC source before it gets to the left side of L1?

I feel you must understand why I wrote as I did to understand remediation I might suggest. The bridge rectifier subsystem on the left is a common starting point. The switcher subsystem on the right is a common topology, too. But there is usually something put in between them. Have you looked over any working schematics that include these two subsystems? If so, you should readily see what's missing (to my eye, anyway.) Think about what's going on with the bridge and what L1 "sees" looking in that direction. Can you put yourself into a position to see that side of things?

I had a feeling that I would need another capacitor to smooth the ripples from the bridge but i was unsure, this that the avenue you might be hinting?

Generally, yes. But you have an answer that addresses this more clearly.

Thank you, very informative :) . I have another question, what should i consider when selecting an inductor? i dont have many givens and i am not allowed to ask my professor questions, i must work from a PDF and the internet, i find the PDF to not be straight forwards. (I know this may seem a trivial problem for you)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


Any notes or ideas would be amazing.

Well, if you are trying to have a power-factor-corrected regulator then you will still need a small capacitor across the bridge output (i.e. before L1). And also, since the rectified mains (i.e. without any smoothing) will be used as the input to the boost converter, a constant-width pulse will not be enough so you will need a dynamically-adjusted pulse train for the MOSFET in order to get the desired DC output.
If power factor correction is not something you seek then you'll need a relatively large capacitor across the bridge output (again, before L1) to have a good enough DC as the input to your boost converter. The amount of the capacitance depends on a few factors:

Holdup
Acceptable minimum and maximum input voltage for the boost converter
Acceptable ripple (part of the acceptable min and max input)


Thank you, very informative :) . I have another question, what should i consider when selecting an inductor? i dont have many givens and i am not allowed to ask my professor questions, i must work from a PDF and the internet, i find the PDF to not be straight forwards. (I know this may seem a trivial problem for you)

@RichardLewis this is beyond the main topic's scope, I'm afraid. What I can suggest at the moment could be to study boost converter design. You calculate the inductor for a selected peak-to-peak ripple current (which is usually selected between 20% and 40% of the max output current) and the operation mode (CCM: continuous conduction mode, or DCM: discontinuous cond mode). The higher the ripple, the smaller the inductance (therefore the inductor), and vice versa. CCM brings lower ripple, but more loss. You can find other details online.
